# Maven Filter don't work in wtpwebapps folder

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'm generating a war file using some maven-filters settings, look:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
            <escapeString>\</escapeString>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                    <targetPath>/WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <escapeString>\</escapeString>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

When i execute "mvn clean install" and look for "target" folder the filter works very well and i can upload the war file to production, but if i look in wtpwebapps folder generated for eclipse the filter didn't act, Seens like eclipse generated files in wtpwebapps before maven-filter act.

How can i fix this problem and force eclipse to use maven-filter.

Comment: What is your Eclipse version? Is your m2e-wtp up to date?

Comment: I'm using eclipse mars. How can i can see m2e-wtp version ?

Comment: Use this URL to update it http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/mars/ through the "Install new Software" dialog.

Comment: I installed the m2e-wtp but source codes in wtpwebapps folder continue without maven-filter.

Comment: Now works, i use the "Maven - Update Project"